# Convert char[] with random char element(s) into one int

Tags: c++

I have been trying to read the binary data in an STL file using C++. I found some methods on the web which include one procedure that I failed to understand:

```
char f1[4] = { facet[0],facet[1],facet[2],facet[3] };
float xx = *((float*)f1);
```

I understand that every *char* can be converted into *int* through their ASCII number, but I have no clue how an array of *char* can be converted into one *int*:

```
char foo[3] = { 'a','b','c' };
int x = (int)foo;
/*x is now 6513249*/
/*And the char[] can be converted into float as well*/
```

What's behind this conversion? What makes one `char[]` a specific int or float?

Comment: As far as conversion goes, i think the first one is interpreting a series of 4 character **values** to a single float(assuming `float` is 4 bytes), the second one, i believe is just converting a pointer value(from the array name decaying to a pointer) to an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us take your two examples separately:

```
char f1[4] = { facet[0],facet[1],facet[2],facet[3] };
```

This declares an array of four `char`, and gives them some values.

```
f1
```

As an expression, this is of type "array of four char elements", but in most contexts this decays into "pointer to char" (to the first element).

```
((float*)f1)
```

This casts the "pointer to char" into a "pointer to float".  It yields a pointer which the compiler has been told points to a float in memory (although actually it points to a an array of char).  This could also be written as:

```
reinterpret_cast<float*>(f1)
```

which makes it much more obvious that something dodgy is going on.

```
*((float*)f1)
```

This indirects through the pointer, and treats the four chars as if they were a float.  It is wandering very close to the edge of the *strict-aliasing* rules, and I think it crosses over them.  Avoid this sort of code.  (Apart from the strict aliasing rules, it can also crash if the CPU requires float variables to be aligned, and the char array isn't suitably aligned).

```
float xx = *((float*)f1);
```

Finally, this declares a float variable, and assigns it the value we calculated above.  This may yield a trap value in xx.

You can avoid most of the dangers with:

```
char f1[4] = { facet[0],facet[1],facet[2],facet[3] };
float xx;
memcpy(&xx, f1, 4);
```

This copies the four bytes from f1 into the memory of xx.  It can still be a trap value, but at least it won't violate the strict aliasing rules, or be misaligned.

```
char foo[3] = { 'a','b','c' };
int x = (int)foo;
```

This is much simpler.  It is casting the address of `foo` into an int, and storing the int in `x`.  This *can* be useful, but usually isn't (particularly as `int` is usually not large enough in 64-bit applications).

Comment: I particularly like that you mentioned about strict alignment considerations of some CPUs.